# Order table by level difficult

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have a table with games in this format:

```
ID | GameName | EasyLevels | HardLevels | TotalLevels

1    Stakeboard  32           28          60

....
```

This table was generated by a xslt file that contains:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//games">
    <tr>
            <th>GameID</th>
            <th>GameName</th>
            <th>EasyLevels</th>
            <th>HardLevels</th>
            <th>TotalLevels</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="game">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="GameId"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="GameName"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(levels/level[leveldifficult='Easy'])"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(levels/level[leveldifficult='Hard'])"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(levels/level)"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
```

And I also have 2 buttons the xslt file. Because I want that be possible to order the table by the number of each level difficult when the button is clicked. But Im not see how to do that in xslt. Do you know how this is possible?

```
<button>Order By Number Of EasyLevels</button>
<button>Order By Number Of HardLevels</button>
```

The xml is like this:

```
<games>
    <game>
        <GameId>1</GameID>
        <GameName>Game Title</GameName>
        <levels>
            <level>
                <environment>City</environment>
                <music>city_40</music>
                <difficult>easy</difficult>
            </level>
            <level>
                ....
            </level>
            ....
        </levels>
    </game>
   ´
     <game>
        <GameId>2</GameID>
        <GameName>Game Title 2</GameName>
        <levels>
            <level>
                <environment>forest</environment>
                <music>forest_100</music>
                <difficult>hard</difficult>
            </level>
            <level>
                ....
            </level>
            ....
        </levels>
    </game>

</games>
```

Comment: XSLT has no user interface. If you want your HTML page to have a sortable table, learn how to do it in HTML/Javascript, then make your XSLT output the required code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But its not possible with javascript when the button is clicked be applied some xslt that sorts the table?

Comment: Probably not. I don't know what you use to initiate the XSLT transform in the first place. Usually, the XML source is no longer available after this. You have the choice of either (1) asking the server to re-serve the page with another sort, or (2) using Javascript to re-sort the existing table.

Comment: I can give you one solution immediately -- as soon as you provide the source XML document (as small as possible, please) on which to apply the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update the question with the xml.

Answer (score 1):

tl dr: You may be looking for the [sort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/xslt_sort.htm) function

**XSLT** already has a sort function that orders the information based on a defined criteria

```
<xsl:sort
   select = string-expression 
   lang = { nmtoken }
   data-type = { "text" | "number" | QName }
   order = { "ascending" | "descending" }
   case-order = { "upper-first" | "lower-first" }
</xsl:sort>
```

Attributes:

- **select** Sorting key of the node.
- **lang** Language alphabet used to
  determine sort order.
- **data-type** Data type of the information (text, value, QName).
- **order** Sorting order (ascending, descending). Default is "ascending"
- **case-order** Sorting order of string by
  capitalization. Default is "upper-first".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your answer its possible to order but it seems that its not possible to order only after the button click.